# Style Corona button differently when disabled?

Tags: api, button, lua, coronasdk, disabled-input

Is it possible to have a button look different when disabled in a Corona app? For example, I have a button like the one below:

```
local button = widget.newButton({label = "Next", onEvent = callback_fn, defaultFile = image.path("Active@2x.png")})
```

Which uses "Active@2x.png" as the default background. Is there a way with the widget library v2 to define a background file that is used when the button is disabled? I am aware of `defaultFile` and `overFile`. It would be nice if there was something like `disabledFile`.

Is there any way to achieve this type of functionality?

Any suggestions are appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

You could create two versions of your button then in the event handler, change which button is displayed. See for example the answer to [How to make buttons stay pressed using corona](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854684/how-to-make-buttons-stay-pressed-using-corona), where you add two buttons to the scene view but set one to invisible, and in the event handler you swap visibility.

Comment: Can you provide some code or a link to an example somewhere with this type of functionality? I figured this is what I would have to do but I am not sure how to begin.

Comment: @Stratus3D I extended my answer, let me know if still unclear

Answer (score 0):

To achieve that you'll need to code it yourself. I personally like to do my buttons with an image and add an event listener to it, something like this:

```
local function methodOnTap( event )
    print("Hey!! you tapped me!")
end

local buttonWithImage = display.newImage( "image.png")
buttonWithImage:addEventListener( "tap", methodOnTap )
```

this is a simple explanation on how to do a button with an image, if you want states and a disabled image, you need to do a group and add the eventListener to that group.